# Hiding text beyond a certain number of characters on html or css

Tags: css

I am attempting to hide text past a single character on my Anki flashcards by changing the code of the notes so that it displays only a single character. All help would be appreciated.
This is the code on the front (in html):

```
<div class="kanji">{{Radical}}<span class="radicon">{{Radical_Icon}}</span></div>

<div class="quest"><b>Kanji Keyword</b></div>

<div class="input">{{type:sort_id}}</div>
```

This is how the text at the "kanji" is displayed (in css):

```
.kanji {
 font-family: "yuumichou";
#font-family:arial;
 font-size:180px;
 color: #abb1d1;
 background-color:#292b36;
}
```

For context, is what the front text for the kanji class looks like:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYvQb.png
(The text past the kanji is the text I'm intending to hide)

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a container for the text that is the size of one character and then set the overflow to hidden so any additional characters can't be seen.

I'm thinking something like:

```
 .kanji {
 font-family: "yuumichou";
#font-family:arial;
 font-size:180px;
 color: #abb1d1;
 background-color:#292b36;
 width: 180px;
 height: 180px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

I'm a beginner, and this may or may not work, but give it a try!

Comment: It worked somewhat however the kanji stayed in the place it was before the text was hidden, making the card look pretty awkward. But it did technically work so thanks for helping me!